# find pattern substring using python re

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to find all substrings within a multi string in python 3, I want to find all words in between the word 'Colour:':

example string:

```
str = """
Colour: Black
Colour: Green
Colour: Black
Colour: Red
Colour: Orange
Colour: Blue
Colour: Green
"""
```

I want to get all of the colours into a list like:

```
x = ['Black', 'Green', 'Black', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Green']
```

I want to do this using Python re

Whats the fastest way of doing this with re.search , re.findall, re.finditer or even another method.

I've tried doing this as a list comprehension:

```
z = [x.group() for x in re.finditer('Colour:(.*?)Colour:', str)]
```

but it returns an empty list ?

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex, the dot `.` does not match new line by default. This mean your program is trying to find something like "Color: blueColor".

To overcome this, you can just do something like :

```
colours = re.findall(r'Colour: (.+)', str)
```

Note the use of `re.findall` to avoid using the list comprehension.

Furthermore, if the format won't change, regex is not mandatory and you can just split each line on spaces and get the second part :

```
colours = [line.split()[1] for line in str.splitlines()]
```

Comment: perfect,  'colours = re.findall(r'Colour: (.+)', str)'  works well, in fact you don't even need the 'r' before 'Colour'  in python 3. the 2nd method with splitlines() gives me an error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: Yeah the r before the string is not necessary but by habit I always use it before a regex string, because regex has a lot of backslashes (\\) and escaping them gets annoying fast.

Answer (score 0):

The lists containing the trailing spaces can be removed and split based on the user-defined variable. In your case, the `Colour:`.

```
list(filter(None, str.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").split("Colour:")))
```

Result:

```
['Black', 'Green', 'Black', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Green']
```

###### Regard to time constraints:

Regex patterns are subjected to taking more time than dealing with strings directly.

Adding the image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need a simple one-liner:

```
x = re.findall("Colour: (.*)",str)
```

This worked for your example.

(P.S. please don't use builtin symbols like `str` for variable names.)

Comment: also a simple method, and yes the 'str' name is just used here for example and not in  code.

Comment: Just changing from `str` to `myString` or `example_string` or `argstr` could also show your example.  Remember, many of us will cut and paste example code (as I did) to run your example.  Avoiding shadowing builtins eliminates unexpected behavior.